# Is it okay to use stative verbs in Topic-Comment?

Tags: usage, verbs

In the topic-comment structure, I notice that action verbs and adjectival verbs often appear in the comment part. This makes sense because the topic is typically an object: with action-verbs, you can comment on the topic in a performative manner (I watched it, I read it, He arrived etc); with adjectival verbs, likewise you can describe the object with adjectives (very good, a lot of, very fast etc).

Curiously, I don't see many **stative verbs** (like 喜歡，需要，希望，想，覺得）used in the comment. For example:

> 我喜歡這個人

Would it also be okay to say: 這個人我喜歡

Other examples:

> 我需要買汽車 Or: 買汽車我需要
>
> 春捲我想要 Or: 我想要春捲
>
> 她奶奶我想念 Or: 我想念她奶奶

Are there potential differences in meaning between the two formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 'topic-comment structure', the topic and the comment cannot swap places. If they can, the sentence would not be a topic-comment structure. It is just a 'object placed before verb' sentence

Examples

> 這個人(object) 我喜歡 (subject + verb) [O]
>
> 我喜歡(subject + verb) 這個人 (object) [O]
>
> 這個人 (topic)  不是好人 (comment) [O]
>
> 不是好人(comment) 這個人(topic) [X]

More examples:

> 我去过(subject + V) 中国 (object) [O]
>
> 中国 (object) 我去过(subject + V) [O]
>
> 攻擊中國 (topic) 對美國沒有好處 (comment) [O]
>
> 對美國沒有好處 (comment) 攻擊中國 (topic) [X]

Now look at your other examples:

> 我需要買(subject +v) 汽車(object) [O]
>
> 汽車(object) 我需要買(subject +v) [O]
>
> 她奶奶(object)  我很想念(subject + verb)[O]
>
> 我很想念(subject + verb) 她奶奶(object) [O]

None of the above is 'topic-comment' sentences

Example of stative verbs in comment

> 攻擊中國 (topic) 大家都[覺得]對美國沒有好處 (comment)
>
> 美國攻擊中國 (topic) 我[希望]只是一個謠言 (comment)

Comment: Didn't realize there was a difference thank you! With the stative verbs 覺得 and 希望 in your examples, are they in brackets because they're implied and not necessary?

Comment: They are  in brackets just to make them stand out more, also you can replace them with other verbs as long as the sentence make sense

Answer (score 1):

Putting the “object” in front of the sentence is to emphasize, express a strong emotion, and it is also a rhetorical technique-排比句。
Example:
面包会有的，牛奶会有的，一切都会有的。
Can be written as：
面包，会有的；牛奶，会有的；一切，都会有的。